# AngularJS Pie Chart not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have the following Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-charts/0.2.7/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chart-module.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following chart-module.js:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope) 
{
   $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
   $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});
```

When I run the Index.html on chrome, the pie chart is not displayed.
I have tried and searched for solutions but none are working for me.

I am getting no errors on chrome console.
I have followed [this](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer the matching versions of chart.js and angular-chart.js

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

**`DEMO`**

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"])
.controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope){
   $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
   $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="PieCtrl">
   <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it.